# HTML5 Video Background not working on Safari

Tags: html, video, background, safari

This is the website that I'm building: http://franciscouto.pt/woodkid/
It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari. The website doesn't even load. It always give the error "A problem repeatedly occurred with "http://franciscouto.pt/woodkid/" Reload webpage.
Thanks in advance

Comment: wow, not only gets an error, but crashes Safari for me. have you tried removing various elements (the `svg`, the `webm` video) to try and determine what's causing it to explode? if you use the `canPlayType` method you could make things more specific if it's video, but my guess is there's something in the `svg` that makes it explode

Comment: Yap. It was the svg. That's really weird. Do you know any fix ?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal just fixed the svg. Thanks